# Return different columns in query result in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE analysis (
       id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
       offer1 numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL,
       roi1 numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL,
       offer2 numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL,
       roi2 numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL, 
       offer3 numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL,
       roi3 numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Basically it contains number of offers for a good.
I'm looking for a way to select id and only two columns as offer and roi where roi is the biggest value among all the offers. How this can be done?

Comment: You’ll have to show some example input and output data or explain a bit more what you want to achieve, this explanation isn’t really clear

Comment: I would recommend to normalize your table, i.e create another table ```offers``` with two fields ```offer``` and ```roi``` you can then use aggregate in your query for more details follow this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: Your dat is not even in 2NF - you have repeating groups. Change your table to have only one offer and one roi and have multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really only going to use this for 3 offers and 3 rois, then you could do this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN offer1 > offer2 THEN
      CASE WHEN offer1 > offer3 THEN offer1 ELSE offer3 END
    WHEN offer2 > offer3 THEN
      offer2
    ELSE
      offer3
  END AS offer,
  CASE
    WHEN offer1 > offer2 THEN
      CASE WHEN offer1 > offer3 THEN roi1 ELSE roi3 END
    WHEN offer2 > offer3 THEN
      roi2
    ELSE
      roi3
  END AS roi
FROM
  analysis
```

If you are going to do it for more than just 3, you might want to consider a different data structure where you have something like:

```
CREATE TABLE
  offers
(
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  good_id BIGINT,
  offer numeric(19, 2) NOT NULL,
  roi numeric(12, 2) NOT NULL
)
```

Where all the offers for one good share the same good_id. Then you could do an aggregate query to get your answer.